# Meaning of pending machine in autosys

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

Many time I have seen some of our `autosys jobs` go into status: `Pending Machine`. What is the meaning of this status? And its generally the com job and not the box job that goes into this status (box is in running status). Any idea how can this issue be resolved?

**Update** - Got the reason for Pending Machine status. It was due to file system, the disk quota usage was 100% and the autosys agent stopped working because of it. 
When we made some space and restarted the agent, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a situation when the machine is blocked in wcc of Autosys.
Check the status of the machine:

Run the command `autorep -m ALL | grep $(mc_nm)`

This will return the status of the machine. If it is blocked, then from wcc frontend, mark the machine as offline and then mark it as online. It will restart the agent on the machine and the issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The AutoSys agent is likely `Offline`.  You can check the machine status as: `autorep -M $hostname`

Example output:

```
Machine Name            Max Load   Current Load Factor  O/S         Status
_______________________ __________ ____________ _______ ___________ ______
clown-car.big-corp.com  ---        ---          1.00    Sys Agent   Missing
```

How to fix it?  On Windows, there is a service called "CA Workload Automation Agent".  Make sure it is running.  For UNIX, I don't know.  Also, maybe your agent was (accidentally) uninstalled.

Note: On my ancient version of AutoSys, from `autorep -J $job_name -d`, the job status for `Pending Machine` is a measly `PE`.  Tough to decipher!